# Run ASP.NET Web API Hourly to fetch data from Database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for the best way to call web api hourly to retrieve data from SQL server. I have the asp.net web API but not sure which approach/technology I should use to run it hourly. Any suggestion/piece of code or technological idea would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Use either a Windows Service or a Console App that's executed via a scheduled task.

Of course, this would only make sense if the machine your hoping to initiate the calls from doesn't already have access to your database. If it does, consider just making the database call directly. If you can't make the database call directly, just be sure you can reach your Web API via port 80 or 443.